# <package> uses or overrides a deprecated API

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle

I was trying to upgrade my project to some of the latest versions, I'm unable to get to null-safety since some of the dependencies in the project haven't been updated.

I've resorted to sdk version 2.10, along with that I updated all core packages with resolved all the breaking changes. Some of the deprecated changes (i.e FlatButton to TextButton, hasn't been resolved yet).

I ran into a couple problems building the solution, and after consulting some old Stack posts I've cobbled together gradle file updates, upgrade to Android Studio etc...

However, I'm receiving warnings when I build the solution as  uses or overrides a deprecated API and when it installs on the virtual device it fails launch without providing an error.

I'm wondering whether my hacks on the gradle files are the cause - I wanted to get a confirmation whether these gradle updates are correct (specifically the versions that are in use).

App > Android > build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App > Android > App > build.grade

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 29
    
        sourceSets {
            main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        }
    
        lintOptions {
            disable 'InvalidPackage'
        }
    
        defaultConfig {
            // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
            applicationId "com.<appname>.app"
            minSdkVersion 23
            targetSdkVersion 29
            versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
            versionName flutterVersionName 
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
                // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            }
        }
    }
    
    flutter {
        source '../..'
    }
    
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    
    dependencies {
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
        
    
    }
    
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

app > android > wrapper > gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

pubspec.yaml package versions :

```
cloud_firestore: ^2.2.1
firebase_auth: ^1.2.0
firebase_core: ^1.2.0
firebase_analytics: ^8.1.0
cloud_functions: ^1.1.0
firebase_storage: ^8.1.0
firebase_messaging: ^10.0.0  
google_sign_in: ^5.0.4
devicelocale: ^0.3.2
image_cropper: ^1.4.0
local_auth: ^1.1.6
```

pubspec.yaml SDK Version

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.10.0 <3.0.0"
```

Debug console warnings/note :

> Running "flutter pub get" in app... Warning: You are using these
> overridden dependencies: ! font_awesome_flutter 8.8.1 from path
> /Users/prad/Development/packages/font_awesome Launching lib/main.dart
> on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode... Note:
> /Users/prad/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/devicelocale-0.3.2/android/src/main/java/com/example/devicelocale/DevicelocalePlugin.java
> uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
> -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: /Users/prad/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.2.1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java
> uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
> -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: /Users/prad/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-2.2.1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/firestore/FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin.java
> uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
> -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: /Users/prad/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-2.2.1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/firestore/streamhandler/TransactionStreamHandler.java
> uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
>
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. Note:
> /Users/prad/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_analytics-8.1.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseanalytics/FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.java
> uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
> -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: /Users/prad/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_analytics-8.1.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseanalytics/FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.java
> uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
>
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. Note:
> /Users/prad/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_functions-1.1.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/functions/FlutterFirebaseFunctionsPlugin.java
> uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
> -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: /Users/prad/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-1.2.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/auth/FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin.java
> uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
> -Xlint:deprecation for details. /Users/prad/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_storage-8.1.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/storage/FlutterFirebaseStoragePlugin.java:38:
> warning: [deprecation] Registrar in PluginRegistry has been deprecated
> public static void registerWith(PluginRegistry.Registrar registrar) {
> ^ 1 warning Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
> -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for
> details. Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note:
> /Users/prad/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_secure_storage-4.2.0/android/src/main/java/com/it_nomads/fluttersecurestorage/FlutterSecureStoragePlugin.java
> uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
> -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: /Users/prad/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_sign_in-5.0.4/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/googlesignin/GoogleSignInPlugin.java
> uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
> -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: /Users/prad/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_cropper-1.4.0/android/src/main/java/vn/hunghd/flutter/plugins/imagecropper/ImageCropperPlugin.java
> uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
> -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: /Users/prad/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/local_auth-1.1.6/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/localauth/LocalAuthPlugin.java
> uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
> -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
> ✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk. Lost connection
> to device.

The Virtual Device I'm using is Pixel 3a API version 29.

Comment: Maybe this answere helps: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66830450/note-recompile-with-xlintdeprecation-note-some-input-files-use-or-override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66830450/note-recompile-with-xlintdeprecation-note-some-input-files-use-or-override)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If some of the plugins you're using has yet to have support for Flutter null safety, you can add `--no-sound-null-safety` argument on your build as mentioned on this [guide](https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety#testing-or-running-mixed-version-programs). This argument should let you build the Flutter project even if some of the plugins used doesn't have support for null safety.